# Ready to use C++ iomanip wrappers?

Tags: library, c++

[Copied from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418943/ready-to-use-c-iomanip-wrappers). (Looking at the the [FAQ](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'd say it is on topic here.)

- A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story

➔ Make `iostreams` less verbose to use and prevent errors wrt. stickiness / non stickiness of flags.

- Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

➔ Provide a wrapper function for each of the [format flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) as well as the [fill, precision and width](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) options.

---

Since raw use of the [iomanip](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) stream modifiers is a) verbose and b) error prone ([sticky vs. non-sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky), etc.), for user defined types, all that stuff can be hidden in the default `operator<<` ... as [shown here, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328411/effective-use-of-c-iomanip-library).

However, when formatting built-in types (even from within a user defined operator), it would be much more convenient (IMHO) to use an approach similar to [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)<sup>(beware C++14)</sup>, where the data is wrapped in a function call that returns a temporary object that sets + resets the appropriate flags.

Essentially, instead of [writing](https://github.com/cppformat/cppformat#iostreams):

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << 1.23456 << "\n";
```

you would hypothetically write:

```
using namespace shorter;
std::cout << precis(2, fixed(1.234556)) << "\n";
```

As the example shows, combination of flags could get tricky and I'm sure the devil is in the details, so I was wondering whether there is any prior art / exiting helper library that tries to address "chevron hell". :-)

- Is there any existing library addressing this?
- What are the technical pitfalls here, if one wants to come up with a set of helpers oneself?

Specifically, this question is not about any kind of "type safe format string" (like Boost.Format offers).

I'm also not asking for a "best" library, I'm asking about *any* library doing this for normal ostreams. (Because I was not able to find any.)

For example, the [write API of C++ Format](http://cppformat.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#write-api) does something like this, but it doesn't do it for std::iostreams, but for the library's "stream" type:

```
MemoryWriter out;
out << pad(hex(0xcafe), 8, '0');
```

Comment: I've not noticed anything like that, but - are you sure it's that difficult to write yourself? (Yes, I realize you don't want to re-invent the wheel...) Sounds like you could implement a few of these suggestions in a not-so-long .hpp file.

Comment: @einpoklum - it probably isn't that difficult to do. It would just have been nice if someone already done it. I mean, look at all the fluff in boost. Why isn't there something like this? :-)

Comment: Fair question. I still don't understand how come nobody has written something like [this](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26611/a-c-library-for-configurable-pretty-printing-dumping-array-contents).